# How to pass cell value to a SUM function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to do a SUM of last 12 rows in the column (I'll be adding more rows into this column so I wanted to automate the calculation).

First of all, I am able to get the value of last cell with some value in this column by `=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((B1:B200<>"")*ROW(B1:B200)))` - result is stored in C1. However, I am not sure how to use this value inside the SUM formula, I was thinking something like `=SUM(B(get value of C1)-12:B(get value of C1)`.

I tried multiple things but none of them have worked - I also don't mind using a different approach if it gets the job done.

Comment: I upvoted since I believe it is a fair question. Please check my answer if it suits your needs.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own custom function to do that using Google Apps Script (GAS).

Try the following:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  if ( col==2  && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Sheet1" ){ 
   e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange("C1").setValue(sumLast12());     
}
}

function sumLast12() {
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet_size = sheet.getLastRow();
  var elmt = sheet.getRange("B1:B"+sheet_size).getValues().flat([1]);
  var elmt12 = elmt.slice(-12);
  var sum = 0;
for( var i = 0; i < elmt12.length; i++ ){
    sum += parseInt( elmt12[i], 10 );
}
  return sum;
}
```

**Explanation**:

- In order to activate this functionality go the menu bar on top of the
  spreadsheet file and click on **Tools => Script editor** and copy the
  aforementioned code into a blank script document (see attached
  screenshot for more information) and save the document (cntrl+s).
- After the script has been saved, everytime you edit a cell in column
  **B** (either by adding a new value on the bottom or modify an existing value, the script will automatically update the value in
  cell **C1** with the sum of the last 12 values in column **B**.

Note that if you don't want to change my code, name the sheet you are working with as **Sheet1**.

[image: Explanation]

Comment: Uh, I haven't expect anything that complicated for such a simple thing to be honest :) I can try later on, thanks for your answer!

Comment: It is super easy. It is an one time thing. You just have to copy this code to the script editor once and that is all.

Comment: At least try it out and if there is a better solution you can always delete it. Google scripts in general is a powerful tool that will elevate the capabilities of your spreadsheet files.

Comment: Yeah, it's working, it took me like two minutes :) I didn't question easiness of the solution, I just thought that there will be some concatenation trick inside a formula or something like that :)

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
=SUM(FILTER(B:B,ROW(B:B)>=MAX(ROW(B:B))-12)
```

Comment: No, this one actually returns `0`.

Comment: @PetrMensik Maybe if you shared a sample sheet I could better demonstrate how to do it.  I think it should be fairly simple.